# 2 Generic list assignment

Tags: c#, generics

if  class type list is there named

```
Collection<PurchaseOrderDetail> poDetails = new Collection<PurchaseOrderDetail>();
```

and another list with same type is there named _poH.PODetail

why  `_poH.PODetail = poDetails.ToList();` generates an error

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'
 to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection'

what is the solution for this, any explanation please.

All the reason behind the question is

```
_poH.PODetail = poDetails;
```

made  `poDetails.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex));` updates as well so I was searching for some thing like _poH.PODetail = poDetails.ToCollection();

Comment: because `Collection` is not a base type for `List`

Comment: Following up on your edit: this is because `Collection<T>` is a reference type, like most of the types are inside .NET. Any variable or type member which uses such types are actually "pointing" towards an instance. This means that unless `PurchaseOrderDetail` is a `struct` (which are value types), any properties you change in one will ALSO be reflected in any collections it's in, EVEN if there are many actual instances or even kind of collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, `_poH.PODetail` is of type [`Collection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx), so assigning a list to it doesn’t work. But since `poDetails` is a collection itself, you can just assign it directly:

```
poH.PODetail = poDetails;
```

So you don’t actually need to call `ToList()` on it to convert it to a list.

---

There is no `ToCollection` method you could call on enumerables, but you could use the [`Collection` constructor that takes a list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132401.aspx) to make it wrap that list and create a readonly collection:

```
new Collection(poDetails.ToList());
```

Comment: @@poke I'm just searching for a ToCollection() method but there isn't . I know poH.PODetail = poDetails; this is valid

Comment: @Sanjeewa If you choose to assign the collection directly, you must remember that `Collection<T>` is a reference type. This means that the collection won't be "copied", it will be the same. Adding / removing in either `poDetails` or `_poH.PODetails` will reflect on the other collection variable. This may not be what you want, depending on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is simply that the [`ToList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx) extension returns an instance of [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) class which, although similar, is not the same type as [`Collection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397(v=vs.110).aspx).

Basically this doesn't work for the same reasons you cannot set a string value to an integer variable.

One thing you *can* do though, is initializing the content of a new collection instance with an [`IList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx) instance. Therefore, the following should give you exactly what you want:

```
_poH.PODetail = new Collection(poDetails.ToList());
```

Also, as poke suggested, you might also want to assign the `PODetail` property with the `poDetails` variable itself.

```
_poH.PODetail = poDetails;
```

However, you must remember that `Collection<T>` is a reference type. This means that the objects in your collection won't be "copied" inside `_poH.PODetail`; instead, both `poDetails` and `_poH.PODetail` will be pointing to the exact same collection. Any changes done to one collection will automatically be reflected on the other.